# Font asset not found helvetica.ttf on lollipop

Tags: java, android, fonts, android-5.0-lollipop

For some reason on lollipop, I'm getting this error and since lollipop is so new I can't find out why anywhere and I have no idea how to figure it out. Thanks in advance Logcat error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity                                       
ComponentInfo{com.bent.MissionaryTracker/com.bent.MissionaryTracker.MainActivity}:          
java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found helvetica.ttf
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found helvetica.ttf
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:190)
at com.bent.MissionaryTracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:57)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
... 10 more
```

EDIT: HERE IS THE CODE THAT THROWS THE ERROR

```
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);


    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "helvetica.ttf");
    title.setTypeface(font);
```

I have helvetica.ttf in my assets folder in my project folders.

EDIT: 
This app works on all devices up until 5.0 so for some reason 5.0 is not recognizing the file in my assets folder.

I tried to post a screenshot of it in my assets folder but I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Comment: are you sure you have `helvetica.ttf` in your assets folder

Comment: @insomniac yes. I tried to upload a screenshot of it in my assets folder. The app works fine on all devices until they upgrade to 5.0 and then it crashes on them.

Comment: I'm getting this too. Worked fine from 2.3.0 to 4.4.4 but stopped working in 5.0 lollipop. In my case I'm not getting any errors, it's just using another font.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well, the thing is some are working. I've checked and its not the "embedding" setting (that prevents some fonts working on browsers), as both my working and non-working ones have the same setting: allow print+preview (read-only). They're both TTF as well. Not sure what else to check for.

Comment: Fixed my issue. See my answer below in case it works for you too.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you are working on Android Studio make sure your asset folder is under main and not res
This worked for me

Comment: I always thought the "res" dir was for graphical stuff, its weird that you'd have to make a new . folder. :/

Comment: I am having this issue, and this solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 76):

Now it's better to use for custom fonts [this approach](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html)

Store fonts in **res/font**

To get typeface use :

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);
```

Comment: yes
To use the Fonts in XML feature on devices running Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher, use the Support Library 26. For more information on using the support library, refer to the Using the support library section.

Look into docs

Comment: This is absolutely the best answer now, glad I scrolled down

Comment: BEST ANSWER IN STACKOVERFLOW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!. you are a hero

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it allows the developer to use the new [Font Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/font-resource) approach regardless of api levels.

Comment: createFromAsset() expects AssetManager and String as attribute -> can't compile with api28, since R.font.myfont returns int.

Answer (score 33):

I had this problem too before I realized I didn't put "fonts/" before the .otf file

```
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/TTMastersDEMOBlack.ttf");
```

Comment: This only works if your font folder is named "fonts"

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me. In my case it didn't work because I created assets folder in res and not in main.

[image]

Comment: Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getResources().getAssets(), "saumil_guj.ttf"); this line work for me

Answer (score 8):

If changing the directory doesn't work it could be due to a problem already fixed  by the Android team but didn't make it in time for 5.0. It's all explained here:

https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=608&thanks=608&ts=1404735239

The workaround (at least it was for me) is to fix the font files with TTX as mentioned in the linked issue.

Getting TTX to work can be a bit of a hassle if you have no python expertise so I ended up downloading [Adobe's AFDKO](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html) that includes TTX. You have to run 'ttx yourfontfile.ttf' that'll turn yourfile to .ttx and then run it again 'ttx yourfontfile.ttx' to get a new .ttf that works with 5.0.

Comment: The most straightforward assumption to make here is that these font files weren't in the right directory.

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky: I tried that at the time and it didn't work. Maybe Google has fixed it by now. Of course, you should first try putting it in another directory, but if that doesn't work (I repeat, it didn't for me) check if the font file is ok. I updated the answer to explain it better.

Answer (score 6):

Clean the project, it helped me on android 6.0

Comment: Spun my wheels uselessly for 30 minutes before I used this suggestion and fixed my problem. Albeit, I had to clean my project TWICE :P
Thank you very much for this suggestion!

Comment: But the issue is on android device and there is not thing such as project in the device

Answer (score 5):

Just place a assets folder inside main directory.
After do this:

```
 Typeface typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue before. I deleted x.ttf and then undid the deletion, tried to run with no lock. So my fix was just to delete it and downloaded the font again and pasted it to fonts/ folder and every thing worked fine.

Comment: This is the preferred option if you have copied your fonts from another project

Answer (score 2):

Ok Guys,

I ran into the same problem. First of all I made my font loading logic crash proof:

```
/**
 * Init method. This method must be called before any other call in this class.
 */
public static void init () {
    fontPlain  = createFont( "helvetica.ttf" , Typeface.NORMAL );
    fontBold   = createFont( "helveticab.ttf", Typeface.BOLD   );
}

/**
 * Load font from assets font folder.
 */
public static Typeface createFont (String font, int style) {
    Typeface typeface;
    try {
        AssetManager assets = Kit.getAppContext().getAssets();
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset( assets, "fonts" + File.separator + font );
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // createFromAsset() will throw a RuntimeException in case of error.
        Log.e( Constants.TAG, "Unable to create font: " + font, e );
        typeface = Typeface.defaultFromStyle( style );
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

And then I also downloaded another font from this project in git:

https://github.com/dimanchec3/Tutoriapps-Android/blob/master/assets/Helvetica.ttf

I realized that my old font was 56KB and this new font is 84KB. I guess I had an older version of the font.

*Please make sure you have the proper license before using this font.*

Comment: do you know the difference between the two fonts? I'm have the issue with a different font

Comment: I am sorry I am not a font expert. But it seemed either an older version or a corrupted one.