# Custom Typeface issue on Lollipop Version

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-typeface

I am facing a weird issue with Lollipop version devices. I am using HelveticaNeue in my app. The text and Numbers are not aligned bcz of it looking weird. 
 [image: With Custom Typeface :]

[image: Without Custom Typeface :]

Please help if anyone has faced this issue. I have tested on Moto G, E, Samsung S4, Nexus 7.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986932/font-asset-not-found-helvetica-ttf-on-lollipop

Comment: @Yogendra , I am not having the error for HelveticaNeue not found and all. Any way thanks for the help.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=608&thanks=608&ts=1404735239

Comment: http://zapone.org/barton/2015/01/01/custom-fonts-not-working-in-lollipop/