# RuntimeException: Font asset not found optimale_bold.ttf

Tags: android, runtimeexception, custom-font

Here is the error line:

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "optimale_bold.tff");
```

Here is the error log cat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found optimale_bold.tff
at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:192)
at com.leontheprofessional.test.whorepresentsyou.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5351) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

Here is the structure of assets folder:
in `main` directory:

```
|-assets
|--optimale_bold.ttf
|-java
|-res
AndrodMainifest.xml
```

in `Android` view of AndroidStudio:

```
|-app
|--manifest
|--java
|--res
|--assets
|---optimale_bold.tff
```

I carefully checked the `app.iml` file, such a line is included:

```
<option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
```

What might be wrong?

PS:
I checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986932/font-asset-not-found-helvetica-ttf-on-lollipop), and tried every solution. But none works. This is not a duplicate post. Please help solve the problem.

To those who might need:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "blahblah"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: `Font asset not found optimale_bold.tff` This tells you that you don't have such font `optimale_bold.tff` in your assets folder.

Comment: I have that font file in the `assets` folder, with exactly the same name.

Comment: So, in your opinion, **why** does it tell you that **it doesn't find it**?

Comment: Possibly, your assets folder has not been created in the path where it's expected to be

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have some misspelling error. Your font extension should be .**ttf**, and not .**tff**

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to add fonts folder inside assets and then use this line,

```
Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/optimale_bold.tff");
```

Also to make sure that the assets folder sits in the same level as java and res.

Answer (score 1):

```
Typeface face1= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/optimale_bold.ttf");
```

Font Name: extentions should be `ttf`, not `tff`

Answer (score 0):

emm, In my case ,it was because the ttf resource has broken when i copy them,so i repeat copy and fix it